# Laptop boots with blank screen but HDMI Monitor is working

Tags: installation, boot, 13.04, intel-graphics

English translation:

Hello all, can you help me fix this problem.  I installed Ubuntu on my notebook for the first time. My laptop is an ACER ASPIRE 5336 I installed Ubuntu while connected to an external HDMI monitor because my laptop does not work and you see black screen. How can  I fix this?

---

Original Spanish:

Problema mi portatil con pantalla negra pero HDMI monitor si funciona

Hola a todos, podéis ayudarme como solucionar el problema.  Mi portátil, queremos instalar ubuntu por primera vez.

Mi portátil tiene marca es ACER y su modelo es ASPIRE 5336 He instalado ubuntu desde HDMI monitor porque mi portátil no funciona y se ve pantalla negra.

Como se soluciona? Por favor

Mil gracias.

Comment: Use the 'xrandr' command in a terminal, to get the names of your displays. E.g. 'LVDS-1', is my laptop screen, and 'HDMI-1' is an external monitor. Then use that id with the xrandr command to switch the dead screen on: 'xrandr --output "LVDS-1" --auto'